# How to discard result in Scalaz State traversal

Tags: scala, scalaz

Example:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

def setS(i: Int): State[List[Int], Unit] = modify(i :: _)

val state = (1 to 1000000).toList traverseS setS

val (finalState, result) = state(Nil)
```

My state function `setS` has result type of `Unit`. It means I am not interested in the result. Yet, when I run my state one million times like this, I'll end up with the `result` collection containing one million instances of `Unit` that I am going to discard immediately with `val (finalState, _) = state(Nil)`. That seems wasteful.

Is there a way to run this kind of State transformation without collectiing results ?

**Solution from [example-of-state-and-free-monad-in-scalaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965215/example-of-state-and-free-monad-in-scalaz) :**

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import Free._

def setS(i :Int) :State[List[Int], Unit] = modify(i :: _)

val s = (1 to 1000000).foldLeft(state[List[Int], Unit](()).lift[Trampoline]) {
   case (st, i) => st *> setS(i).lift[Trampoline]
}

val (finalState, result) = s(Nil).run
```

**I guess you can always write something like:**

```
def traverseUnitS[S](t :Traversable[State[S, Unit]]) :State[S, Unit] = State[S, Unit] {
  state0 =>
    val sout = t.foldLeft(state0)((s, st) => st.run(s)._1)
    (sout, ())
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, although it doesn't collect results, using Free monad as above, is incredibly slow.

Comment: You can also use `traverse_` in `StateT[Trampoline, List[Int], _]`, but it'll be just as slow.

Answer (score 0):

Use `traverseS_` instead of `traverseS`.

Comment: With traverseS_ I get stack overflow. I have to avoid folding over State monad because it will blow the stack with sufficiently large collection.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ How does it not? The question is "Is there a way to run this kind of State transformation without collectiing results ?" and this is exactly what `traverseS_` does.

Comment: @rightføld i reviewed this answer as above, because it is to short, provides no actual explanation how it works and what problem it solves, and also because Dragisa mentioned that is doesn't work for his problem.

Comment: There is an answer from @TravisBrown using Free monad that seems to work.